# liquibase cassandra getting failed

Tags: cassandra, liquibase

I am using liquibase for creating cassarndra. My liquibase version is **3.0.0** and But its showing the following error.

```
D:\Liquibase -Cassandra\common-model\build.xml:89: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.LockException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL CREATE TABLE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID INT NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED datetime, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID)); on jdbc:cassandra://192.168.1.219:9160/ems_testINSERT INTO DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID, LOCKED) VALUES (1, FALSE): line1:121 missing EOF at ',' (... datetime, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255)[,] CONSTRAINT...)
'CREATE TABLE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID INT NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED datetime, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCKPRIMARY KEY (ID))'
    at liquibase.Liquibase.dropAll(Liquibase.java:555)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.dropAll(Liquibase.java:535)
    at liquibase.integration.ant.DropAllTask.execute(DropAllTask.java:54)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
 Caused by: liquibase.exception.LockException:liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL CREATE TABLE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID INT NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED datetime, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID)); on jdbc:cassandra://192.168.1.219:9160/ems_testINSERT INTO DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID, LOCKED) VALUES (1, FALSE): line  1:121 missing EOF at ',' (... datetime, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255)[,] CONSTRAINT...) 'CREATE TABLE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID INT NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED datetime, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCKPRIMARY KEY (ID))'
    at liquibase.lockservice.LockServiceImpl.acquireLock(LockServiceImpl.java:122)
```

This is my ANT target in build.xml

```
<target name="dropAll" depends="prepare" >
    <dropAllDatabaseObjects 
            driver="${db.driver}"
            url="${db.url}"
            username="${db.username}"
            password="${db.password}"
            promptOnNonLocalDatabase="yes"
            classpathref="classpath"
            />      
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Offhand, this looks like a bug in Liquibase. I would suggest trying it again with the latest version of Liquibase to see if it may have been fixed already, and if you can still reproduce it, file a bug in the Liquibase JIRA: https://liquibase.jira.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: I am also tried with latest version (3.3.2) , it also having the same issue.

Comment: @ArunMRNair . I dont know if i can ask this here...i am trying to use liquidbase-cassandra ...can you please pass the instructions to use it ..

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase requires the use of an extension to support Cassandra. Either https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-cassandra should work, or you can try https://github.com/jsanda/cassandra-liquibase-ext

Comment: ya. i am using  https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-cassandra ,but its show s the error.

Comment: With liquibase-cassandra installed, it should be running the LockServiceCassandra class instead of the standard LockServiceImpl class which is throwing the error. Can you make sure the liquibase-cassandra jar is in the same classloader as Liquibase?

Comment: did we need to make liquibase-cassandra jar for that. Currently i am using the jar that present in lib folder.

Comment: It looks like there isn't an official build in https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-cassandra/releases yet. I'll create a snapshot that works with 3.3.2 and add it to the releases. Then you will need to add that jar to your lib directory along with the liquibase.jar file

Comment: Ok.From where i get your jar.

Comment: Sorry, still working on it. When it is ready it will be in the releases link in my last comment.

Comment: @NathanVoxland any luck with the release? It has been a while.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I've been working on a bunch of different things. I'll try to get a new release out this week.

Comment: I committed fixes to make the cassandra extension compatible with Liquibase 3.4.1 and it is now on the buildserver at https://liquibase.jira.com/builds/browse/CONTRIB-LSB-1/artifact  I don't have a cassandra environment to test with, however. Could you try a snapshot build from the buildserver and let me know how it goes? You can email me directly at nathan@liquibase.org rather than fill up this answer